# Evince animation only works in GNOME Xorg

Tags: xorg, latex, evince, wayland

I noted that my (latex) beamer presentations that include animations in the evince pdf viewer can only be displayed if I log into my Xorg session - instead of wayland. 
Is this the supposed behavior? Does wayland really mess up my pdf presentation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an example to test it here, but it's known that certain applications, such as Eclipse IDE, don't work properly on Wayland yet. GTK+ is fine, but maybe some other piece of code still relies on Xorg calls.

It would be nice if you take the time to report this bug to them.
https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/ReportingBugs

As a workaround, you may call the program as `GDK_BACKEND=x11 evince` (notice the small case x). As a convenience, you may copy the /usr/share/applications/evince.desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications/ and edit that file so the Exec line becomes `Exec=bash -c "GDK_BACKEND=x11 evince %U"`.

Comment: that's a good point. I'll submit a bug report